# Exclude application.properties inside spring boot jar using gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to exclude application.properties from the fat jar created by gradle for a Springboot application. I can do it in maven. Gradle is the preferred build tool for the project. I tried to used exclude in the 'jar' task. It is not working. Any other suggestions ?

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
id 'java'}
group = 'com.prasad'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
jar {
     exclude('application.properties')
     //tried this too exclude('src/main/resources/application.properties')
}
```

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to exclude it?

Comment: I want the application to use an external file rather than an internal one. I am currently using -Dspring.config.location in the command line to specify the external location. However, I do not want it inside the packed jar.

Comment: _Why_ do you not want it inside the packed jar? It is normally highly valuable for setting structural application settings such as JSON formatting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Excluding resources is usually the wrong approach. I would simply remove it from `src/main/resources`. If you use it for testing purposes, put it in `src/test/resources`. If you use it for the local `bootRun` task, you can configure that particular task with a path to a application.properties file which you can put somewhere else.

However, if you really like to exclude it, the pattern is correct. You are just not excluding it from the `bootJar` (fat jar) but only the normal `jar` (which is disabled by default when using the Spring Boot plugin). Try with:

```
bootJar {
     exclude('application.properties')
}
```

Comment: thank you! it worked for me.